# format email body - .net 4.0

Tags: c#, email, .net-4.0

I'm using the following to send email  from a site done in .net 4, c#.

```
MailMessage nMail = new MailMessage();
nMail.To.Add("new.address@test.com");
nMail.From = new MailAddress("me@me.com");
Mail.Subject = (" ");
nMail.Body = (" ");                                                   
SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("our server");
sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("login", "pwd");
sc.Send(nMail);
```

Works fine, only thing I don't know how to do is format the body of the message to have multiple lines and include fields from the page itself.
Any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to make a message body with multiple lines.

```
var bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
bodyBuilder.AppendLine("First line.");
bodyBuilder.AppendLine("Second line.");
nMail.Body = bodyBuilder.ToString();
```

It should be obvious how to pull in values from your form now, too (i.e., the full power of string formatting is at your disposal now).

Comment: You must feel all buffed being a BodyBuilder!

Comment: thanks - do i need to add a reference to use StringBuider? not getting it with intellisense...

Comment: @DarkWinter: You need to add a `using` for `System.Text`.

Answer (score 1):

You can send message as HTML. Use IsBodyHtml property

```
MailMessage nMail = new MailMessage();
nMail.To.Add("new.address@test.com");
nMail.From = new MailAddress("me@me.com");
Mail.Subject = (" ");
nMail.Body = ("Line<br/>New line"); 
nMail.IsBodyHtml = true;                                                  
SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("our server");
sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("login", "pwd");
sc.Send(nMail);
```